# Picture Racing across the screen

Tags: java

So I have to create a program where I select three pictures and each of them have to move across the screen at different speeds, and then the program outputs who is in 1st place, 2nd place, and 3rd place. The while loop also has to run 3 times (3 races). So far, I have done it so that the race is completed only once, but I am having trouble on how to make each of the races random each time. Every time I was to run the race now, the results would not change. How would you make it so that the results of the race are actually random? Also, how do you make the loop run 3 times?

```
public class HeadCoachRacing2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        RacerCanvas race = new RacerCanvas (800,800);
        int xPos1 = 1;
        int xPos2 = 1;
        int xPos3 = 1;
        int x = 1;
        String first="";
        String second="";
        String third="";

    race.setFiles("im1.jpg", "im2.png", "im3.png");
    race.moveRacer1(xPos1,100);
    race.moveRacer2(xPos2,300);
    race.moveRacer3(xPos3,500);

    race.repaint();
    race.showText(false);

    while ((xPos1<=650) && (xPos2<=650) && (xPos3<=650))
    {
        xPos1 +=(int)(Math.random()*3)+1;
        if (xPos1>=650){
            xPos1=  650;}
            race.moveRacer1(xPos1,100);


        xPos2 +=(int)(Math.random()*1)+1;
        if (xPos2>=650){
            xPos2=650;}
            race.moveRacer2(xPos2,300);


        xPos3 +=(int)(Math.random()*2)+1;
        if (xPos3>=650){
            xPos3=650;}
            race.moveRacer3(xPos3,500);


        race.delay(5);
        race.repaint();


                    if ((xPos1==650) &&(xPos1>xPos2)&&(xPos2>xPos3)){
                        first="Bill Belichick";
                        second="Gary Kubiak/Peyton Manning";
                        third="Rob Ryan";
                    }
                    else if ((xPos2==650)&&(xPos1<xPos2)&&(xPos3<xPos1)){
                        first="Gary Kubiak/Peyton Manning";
                        second="Bill Belichick";
                        third="Rob Ryan";
                    }
                    else if ((xPos3==650)&&(xPos1<xPos3)&&(xPos2<xPos1)){
                        first="Rob Ryan";
                        second="Bill Belichick";
                        third="Gary Kubiak/Peyton Manning";
                    }
                    else if ((xPos1==650)&&(xPos3<xPos1)&&(xPos2<xPos3)){
                        first="Bill Belichick";
                        second="Rob Ryan";
                        third="Gary Kubiak/Peyton Manning";
                    }
                    else if ((xPos2==650)&&(xPos3<xPos2)&&(xPos1<xPos3)){
                        first="Gary Kubiak/Peyton Manning";
                        second="Rob Ryan";
                        third="Bill Belichick";
                    }
                    else if ((xPos3==650)&&(xPos2<xPos3)&&(xPos1<xPos2)){
                        first="Rob Ryan";
                        second="Gary Kubiak/Peyton Manning";
                        third="Bill Belichick";

                    }



                if ((xPos1==650) && (xPos2==650) && (xPos3==650)){
                    race.showText(true);
                    race.setPlaces(first+ "is in First Place!" +third " is in Second Place! "+ second + " is in Third Place!", 100,100, 30);


                                           race.delay(1000);
                    race.repaint();
```

}

```
                }




            }
```

}

Comment: Change your title to actually fit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just finished making something quite similar you are describing but not as complex

I put these methods inside the while loop

```
race.moveRacer1(xPos1,100);
race.moveRacer2(xPos2,300);
race.moveRacer3(xPos3,500);

race.repaint();
```

then i also used the math.random class to add to the distance they would travel along the screen this would make it a random race each time i could post the code if u like.

EDIT: Code from previous game loop

This is only the game loop im not going to post the other classes as it will turn into a novel but this should get you outta trouble.

```
public void race() throws InterruptedException{

    while (counter < 21){

    random = Math.random() * 5;
    horse1 = (int) (horse1 + random);

    random = Math.random() * 5;
    horse2 = (int) (horse2 + random);

        if(horse1 < horse2 & counter == 2){
            System.out.println("There off Maldiean takes the lead");
        }else if(horse1 > horse2 & counter == 2){
            System.out.println("There off Spark Of Life takes the lead");
        }else if(horse1 > horse2 & counter == 10){
            System.out.println("As they come around the bend Spark of life in the lead");
        }else if(horse1 < horse2 & counter == 10){
            System.out.println("As they come around the bend Maldiean's in the lead");
        }else if(horse1 > horse2 & counter == 15){
            System.out.println("On the home strech Spark of life in the lead");
        }else if(horse1 < horse2 & counter == 15){
            System.out.println("On the home strech Maldiean in the lead");
        }else if(horse1 > horse2 & counter >= 20){
            System.out.println("Spark of life Wins");
        }else if(horse1 < horse2 & counter >= 20){
            System.out.println("Maldiean Wins");
        }
        move();
        repaint();
        Thread.sleep(500);
    counter ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if I could get the code... its just that I dont understand how to apply the math.random into this loop at all.